# How can you tell if Win 7 ESU (extended security updates) is installed on a Windows 7 computer?

Tags: windows-7

I know how to install and activate ESU, but I need a scaleable solution for being about to verify via SCCM that ESU is installed and activated.  Doesn't anyone know anything I can query off to collect these machines?  So that machines that are supposed to have ESU and don't I can make sure that it is activated, and also for people running Windows 7 without ESU past 1/14/20,  I can contact them and tell them to either upgrade to Win 10 or buy an ESU license.  I can't seem to find any documentation on this at all.

Answer (score 1):

Use an application such as Nirsoft's [Registry Changes View](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/registry_changes_view.html) to compare a snapshot of the Windows Registry *before* installing Windows 7 Extended Security Updates with the Registry afterwards.

Then use [Microsoft System Center Configuration Manager (SCCM)](https://www.reddit.com/r/SCCM/comments/7woh1f/collect_registry_values_with_hwinv/) to check for those keys and values that indicate activation.

Answer (score 1):

There's a simple command you can run on the system in an Elevated Command Prompt window to see which products are installed and their activation status.

```
slmgr /dlv
```

https://infinitelogins.com/2020/01/12/how-to-activate-windows-7-extended-security-updates-esu/

Answer (score 0):

I use powershell to check and if it finds the license it writes a key into the registry.

I use this key in the registry for the SCCM detection method.

---

$LicenseList = Get-CimInstance SoftwareLicensingProduct -Filter "Name like 'Windows(R) 7, Client-ESU-Year2 add-on for Enterprise,%'"

if ($LicenseList.ID -eq "0e00c25d-8795-4fb7-9572-3803d91b6880" -And $LicenseList.LicenseStatus -eq "1")  {New-Item -Path "HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\MAK\0e00c25d-8795-4fb7-9572-3803d91b6880" -Name "Status" -Value 1 -Force}

---

of course change to what ever license you are looking for
Use slmgr /dlv to see what licenses are installed